# Custom fields in Zoho Invoice

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

Do we need to purchase Zoho membership? Do we need to make any changes in zoho settings?
How to create more then three custom fields in Zoho Invoice..

[image: ZOHO Invoice Example Image]

I cannot find it, so please help me. I also contacted zoho support team.